# How to validate the number of children records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails 4 app with two models.

```
class User 
  has_many :bids
end

class Bid
  belongs_to :user
end
```

A User can only create one bid per week, so I added the following to the Bid table

```
add_column :bids, :expiry, :datetime, default: DateTime.current.end_of_week
```

and the following scopes to the Bid model

```
scope :default, -> { order('bids.created_at DESC') }
scope :active, -> { default.where('expiry > ?', Date.today ) }
```

I can now prevent a User creating multiple Bids at the controller level like so:

```
class BidsController
  def new
    if current_user.bids.active.any?
      flash[:notice] = "You already have an active Bid. You can edit it here."
      redirect_to edit_bid_path(current_user.bids.active.last)
    else
      @bid = Bid.new
      respond_with(@bid)
    end
  end
end
```

But what is the best approach for validating this at the model level?

I've been trying to set up a custom validation, but am struggling to see the best way to set this up so that the current_user is available to the method. Also, am I adding errors to the correct object?

```
class Bid
  validate :validates_number_of_active_bids
  def validates_number_of_active_bids
    if Bid.active.where(user_id: current_user).any?
      errors.add(:bid, "too much") 
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain separation of concerns, keep the current_user knowledge out of the model layer. Your Bid model already has a user_id attribute. Also, I'd add an error like so since the validation is not checking a "bid" attribute on Bid, but rather the entire Bid may be invalid.

```
class Bid
  validate :validates_number_of_active_bids
  def validates_number_of_active_bids
    if Bid.where(user_id: user_id).active.any?
      errors[:base] << "A new bid cannot be created until the current one expires"
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should be in a collaborator service object.  Create a new class that is named appropriately (something like ActiveBid, maybe think a little on the name) That class will be initialized with a current_user and either return the active bid or false.

This limits the logic for this limitation into a single place (maybe some plans in the future can have 2, etc.

Then in the controller do a before_action that enforces this logic.

```
before_action :enforce_bid_limits, only: [:new, create]

private 

def enforce_bid_limits
  active_bid = ActiveBid.new(current_user).call
  if active_bid #returns false or the record of the current_bid
    flash[:notice] = "You already have an active Bid. You can edit it here."
    redirect_to edit_bid_path(bid)
  end
end
```

Later on if you end up needing this logic in several places throw this stuff in a module and then you can just include it in the controllers that you want.